# Set a gateway which is in another subnet

Tags: linux, networking

Here's my problem: I am working with openvswitch, a software which allows me to create software bridges. 
My network is a 192.168.1.x/24 and the gateway is 192.168.1.1.

Thanks to openvswitch I create another network which is 10.10.1.x/24.
I configured with static ips an host on this network (which would be a VM) this way:
/etc/network/ifaces

> auto eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet static
>
> address 10.10.1.3
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> network 10.10.1.0

Now, I want to communicate with 192.168.1.x/24 hosts.
How can I accomplish this?
I don't think I can set 192.168.1.1 as gateway right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM host (or whatever has access to both the internal and "real" network) has to route. This basically as simple as setting `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Could also be in a new file in `/etc/sysctl.d/`, I don't know how "up to date" Debian is.

This will be effective after rebooting. To activate it instantly, run `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.

For painless VM deployment, you could employ `dnsmasq`. Just remember you have to exclude your "real" network from DHCP or mayhem will ensue. ;)